# Best Way To Test IP Proxies with PHP

Tags: php, proxy

I currently have a script that scrapes proxies off websites, but I'm just wondering what the best way to test them would be, I want to test and sort into different categories like

- All
- ALL HTTP
- ALL SOCKS
- Socks 4
- Socks 5
- HTTPS
- HTTP Connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lookup curl's set_opt function or study the protocols yourself and implement it using sockets. Testing proxies can take forever since some are just slow. You don't want to dismiss them too fast. 'Least with curl you can test many at the same time.